# Efficiently keeping track of simulation observables

Tags: python, json, pandas, simulation

I am running time simulations with a time component, where I keep track of some observables (Kinetic Energy, Forces,...). My current implementation uses numpy arrays, which get initialized with zeros at the beginning (shape: (number of timesteps until end, dim of observable)) and get updated in each timestep. Due to instabilities in the simulations and in order to not lose Data I save the arrays every 1000 steps using Json. For shorter simulations this has worked pretty well but for longer ones this has resulted in a bad performance. I suspect that this is due to the whole array being written to file each time.

My question now is if there is some efficient way, which can keep track of the observables and regularly save them? Can Pandas Dataframes do this?

Edit: Added some more context

Comment: Use to save arrays, use `numpy.save` and `numpy.load`. The alternative is to use `numpy.memmap` to transparently work with a memmapped file directly.

Comment: Intuitively I'm thinking you should try to save the arrays asynchronously, might be worth looking into

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been some time, but if anyone's still looking for a convenient way to track simulation's observables, take a look at [this Python package](https://pypi.org/project/simmon/).

It is a simple simulation monitor that lets you track variables and store the data in an output directory. As for your concern about saving the data, this package gives you the choice to enable `autosave`, which automatically saves the data.

Although currently this autosave operation does not happen in another process, the package does provide you with a "live-view" mode that can be toggled on and off during the simulation. This live-view DOES open in a different process. This gives a nice view of the data when the simulation is still running, and potentially does not affect its overall performance.

Here's a simple example using the Simmon package:

```
from simmon import Monitor

# Create a Monitor - this opens an output directory and a window with toggle buttons
# for user control
mon = Monitor('Example Monitor')

# add a tracker to collect data
tr = mon.tracker('x', 'y')  # x and y are data labels

...

# update the tracker throughout the simulation
tr.update(x, y)  # update tracker with new values

...

mon.finalize()  # closes windows and saves unsaved data
```